# Can you provide an example of calling putMFARequestForSite with com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse?

Tags: yodlee

API Docs:
https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/putMFARequestForSite

First, is the property that needs to be specified for security question responses QuesAndAnswerDetails or quesAnsDetailArray? Both are used in the docs, but neither worked for me.

And are these the sub fields that need to be specified?

- answer
- answerFieldType
- metaData
- question
- questionFieldType

The pulled MFA form specifies 'responseFieldType' instead of 'answerFieldType'.

It'd be very helpful if the docs provided sample requests in addition to sample responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the parameter sample which you can refer

```
        cobSessionToken =  73832732723dasd131d
        userSessionToken = 312371283712asd12312
        memSiteAccId=10059700
        userResponse.objectInstanceType=com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[0].answer=karnataka
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[0].answerFieldType=text
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[0].metaData=QUESTION_1
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[0].question=What is the name of your state?
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[0].questionFieldType=label
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[1].answer=Saint Paul HR SEC School
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[1].answerFieldType=text
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[1].metaData=QUESTION_2
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[1].question=What is the name of your first school
        userResponse.quesAnsDetailArray[1].questionFieldType=label
```

Also answerFieldType will take the value of the responseFieldType from getMFAResponseForSite API

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Please update your API docs to reflect this.

Comment: Note for anyone else visiting this page looking for answers with this service; the order IS important in the post data.

Comment: If this is true, why do I get this error when using quesAnsDetailArray: `Null argument specified for: QuesAndAnswerDetails[]`