# Yodlee QuesAndAnswerDetails

Tags: yodlee

I am attempting to debug a Yodlee site authentication issue I am having. I'm sending the credentials via the following endpoint:
POST https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/Refresh/putMFARequestForSite

And this is the error message I am receiving:

```
{
  "errorOccurred": "true",
  "exceptionType": "com.yodlee.core.IllegalArgumentValueException",
  "referenceCode": "_4ef2f3e7-a750-4dfe-a16e-fa4254451897",
  "message": "Null argument specified for: QuesAndAnswerDetails[]"
}
```

I need to be able to test authenticating via MFA with dropdowns (selects). I created a DAG catalog, and replaced one of the DAG Security QA sites with the following configuration I found when googling:

```
<login>
 <flowControlInfo>
 <delayBeforeChallenge>-1</delayBeforeChallenge>
 <delayBeforeLoginComplete>1</delayBeforeLoginComplete>
 <delayAfterLoginComplete>1</delayAfterLoginComplete>
 <expireToken>false</expireToken>
 </flowControlInfo>
 <MFAFlows>
 <MFAFlow flowOrder="1" isModeOfCommunication="1">
 <HelpTitle>MFA Help Title1</HelpTitle>
 <HelpContent>MFA Help Content1</HelpContent>
 <InfoTitle>MFA Info Title1</InfoTitle>
 <InfoContent>MFA Info Content1</InfoContent>
 <MFAChallengeList>
 <MFAChallenge questionType="text" >
 <MFAOption answerType = "dropdown">
 <questionLabel>Please select desired OTP
destination...</questionLabel>
 <answerOptions>
 <!-- The actual email or token will not be sent and is just a
placeholder to show the form -->
 <option isDefaultSelected="1" value="MOBILE_XXX-XXX-1234">MOBILE
XXX-XXX-1234</option>
 <option isDefaultSelected="0" value="HOME_XXX-XXX-2345">HOME XXXXXX-2345</option>
 <option isDefaultSelected="0" value="WORK_XXX-XXX-3456">WORK XXXXXX-3456</option>
 </answerOptions>
 </MFAOption>
 </MFAChallenge>
<MFAChallenge questionType="text" >
 <MFAOption answerType = "dropdown">
 <questionLabel>Please select desired OTP
destination1...</questionLabel>
 <answerOptions>
 <!-- The actual email or token will not be sent and is just a placeholder to show the form -->
 <option isDefaultSelected="1" value="TEXT">TEXT message</option>
 <option isDefaultSelected="0" value="PHONE">Phone Call</option>
 </answerOptions>
 </MFAOption>
 </MFAChallenge>
 </MFAChallengeList>
 </MFAFlow>
 <MFAFlow flowOrder="2">
 <HelpTitle>MFA Help Title1</HelpTitle>
 <HelpContent>MFA Help Content1</HelpContent>
 <InfoTitle>MFA Info Title1</InfoTitle>
 <InfoContent>MFA Info Content1</InfoContent>
 <TokenDetails>
 <DisplayString>Security Key</DisplayString>
 <Value>123456</Value>
 </TokenDetails>
 </MFAFlow>
 </MFAFlows>
</login>
```

In order to get back MFA form info, I am calling:
POST https://rest.developer.yodlee.com/services/srest/restserver/v1.0/jsonsdk/Refresh/getMFAResponseForSite

I can see the dropdowns with real sites, but I can't get a DAG site to reproduce the same behavior. I've also read https://developer.yodlee.com/assets/images/OTP_Documents/Implementation%20Manual%20for%20Enhanced%20MFA%20Support.pdf however when using Site/Provider Id 16442 I get a 403 yodlee internal error response.

I am aware of [Can you provide an example of calling putMFARequestForSite with com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793365/can-you-provide-an-example-of-calling-putmfarequestforsite-with-com-yodlee-core) and am attempting to implement the the suggested fix however I am unable to test using dag accounts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue in production by ensuring only the expected values are passed, and sending them in the expected order as [Can you provide an example of calling putMFARequestForSite with com.yodlee.core.mfarefresh.MFAQuesAnsResponse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793365/can-you-provide-an-example-of-calling-putmfarequestforsite-with-com-yodlee-core) goes into details about which resolved the "Null argument specified for: QuesAndAnswerDetails[]" error.

No update to the providor accounts APIs was required which would have required a major rework. Was still unable to get DAG to work.

Answer (score -1):

From your ask, I see that your are checking our legacy APIs.

We recommend you to use our new Yodlee APIs to integrate into your system.

Integration Guide- https://developer.yodlee.com/Account_Verification/Getting_Started

API Flow-https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount

Test our APIs here- https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/

If you are interested to get your dedicated and secure environment, then please contact

Sales:1 866-374-0948

Comment: Thanks for the answer, to clarify are you saying that the APIs I am currently using do not support my use case? Is there a migration guide to the new APIs?

Comment: They do support. But we recommend you to use our new APIs.

Please find the migration guide- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Migrating_to_Yodlee_API

Hope this helps.